# ADF Copy function comparing watermark against isnull(date1,date2)

Tags: copy, azure-data-factory

Forum Newbie...
I want to utilise the ADF Copy function, to carry out incremental table extracts from one Azure DB to another. Every table in the database that I need all have the same 2 relevant fields i.e. date1, date2. For Watermark comparison purposes, I need to use isnull(date1,date2), but unsure how to do this, i.e. I am not sure how I can add this consistent derived value to the Source as an additional field that can perhaps be added via the Query or Stored Procedure Option on the source, to utilise the @item().source.schema and @item().source.table values that have already been generated as parameters..?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **query** option in the `Copy data` activity source and add a new column in the query itself to get the results of `isnull(date1,date2)` and include the **parameter** values to get the table name instead of hardcoding them as shown below.

In source, select **Query** option under Use query and add dynamic content to `concat()` select statement with parameter values.

```
@concat('select *, isnull(date1,date2) as final_dt from ',pipeline().parameters.schema,'.',pipeline().parameters.table)
```

[image]

**Sink table data output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for clear and speedy reply!

Comment: Hi N, I think I am a little out of my depth. I am using the standard Copy task provided with ADF v2 (which produces JSON array for all the tables I selected). My dataset settings shows Items: @pipeline().parameters.cw_items, but when I go to the Copy activity, this is the only parameter available to me, i.e. it does recognise pipeline().parameters.schema or pipeline().parameters.table. Do I need to create and set these parameters explicitly? If so how? I am obviously missing a step. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a snippet?

Comment: Not sure how to add screen shots. I am not sure what to show you. I am only using the COPY task from ADF, so everything was auto-created. The key thing is that I want to control via incremental load (of multiple tables), which requires isnull(DatelastUpdated,DateCreated), but have been struggling to work out how to bring through this field in the source query

Comment: I am happy to provide whatever you need, but please clarify what you need "snippet" of